# I replaced $scope to a variable and now my angular application doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm doing an Angular application and I read that it's a good practice don't use $scope. So I replaced to a variable, and now the data is not appearing on my page:
It was like this:

```
observatoryApp.controller('AppController', function AppController($scope, $http){
  var $scope = this;
  $scope.years = [];
  $http.get('json/years.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.years = response.data;
    $scope.data = $scope.years[0];
  });
```

Now is like this:

```
observatoryApp.controller('AppController', function AppController($http){
  var self = this;
  self.years = [];
  $http.get('json/years.json').then(function(response){
    self.years = response.data;
    self.data = self.years[0];
  });
```

And the data are not showing on the index.html page:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
  ...
  <select class="year form-control"
    ng-options="year.id for year in years"
    ng-model="data">
  </select>
  ...
</body>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Var new_variable = $scope.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that it's a good practice don't use $scope

That would have been in context of using `controllerAs` alias as alternative.

Unless you use that alias you use the injected `$scope` to assign model properties to. You would never do `var $scope = this;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an alias for the controller.

Example: Change `ng-controller="ctrlName"` to `ng-controller="ctrlName as vm"`

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as vm">
  ...
  <select class="year form-control"
    ng-options="year.id for year in vm.years"
    ng-model="data">
  </select>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: @charlietfl - He did modify the controller.